# check to remove expired posts laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have a post model that will be boosted by user for some certain time and now i have a crone job to be lunched every 15 mins to run a special script to see if post is boosted or finished .
but the problem is that every time it loops all the posts and it takes some certain amount of time i wanted to know if there is any alternative and better ways to do this ?? here is my code below :

```
$boosted = POST::whereIn('status_id', [4, 5, 6])->where('boosted',1)->get();
        foreach ($boosted as $index => $item) {
            if ($item->boosted_until < Carbon::now()) {
                $wish = Wish::find($item->id);
                $wish->boosted = 0;
                $wish->save();
            }
```

Comment: This is an `N+1` query problem. You're performing a new query for each iteration, which is going to be slow. Do you have a relationship between `POST` (sidenote, that's a terrible model name, should be `Post`) and `Wish`? If you did, then you would be able to do `Post::with('wish')->...->get()`, then `$wish = $item->wish;`, and would avoid the `N+1` query problem completely.

Comment: Why don't you try to add the loop as a query, where('boosted_until,'<',Carbon::now())->each(function($item.....).....;

Comment: and i don't understand the relation between Post and Wish, but if you have as relations you can as well try 
Wish::whereHas('posts', function($query).....), You can actually convert this whole thing into one query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is. It's a huge amount of data that can cause execution time error. I suggest you to use queues in laravel https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queues to run it on the background. You can chunk them also into pieces. For example you are about to loop a 100k row of datas. It's best to divide them into pieces so the queue job will work smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

Following my comments on your question, you can have something like but accurate:

*If you have it set as relations*

```php
Wish::whereHas('posts', function($query){ 
    $query->where('boosted_until', '<', Carbon::now());
})->where('boosted', 1)->update(['boosted' => 0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully, we can use eager loading to reduce this operation to just 2 queries. When querying, you may specify which relationships should be eager loaded using the `with` method:

I assume you already have `hasMany` relationship between Post and Wish models

```
// App\Post Model

public function wishes() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Wish');
}


// Controller
//...
$boosted = POST::with('wishes')->whereIn('status_id', [4, 5, 6])->where('boosted',1)->get();
$wishesIDsToUpdate = [];    
foreach ($boosted as $index => $item) {
     if ($item->boosted_until < Carbon::now()) {
       foreach($item->wishes as $wish) {
             $wishesIDsToUpdate[] = $wish->id;
       }
     }                  
}

if(!empty($wishesIDsToUpdate)) {
  Wish::whereIn('id', $wishesIDsToUpdate)->update(['boosted' => 0]);
}
```